# Validation in jquery for bootstrap popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Here is my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveNewCustomer", "Dealer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="form-group-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.MotorType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.MotorType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control required", placeholder = "Motor Type", required = "required" } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.PowerRating, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.PowerRating, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control required", placeholder = "Power Rating", required = "required" } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.InstallationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.InstallationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker required", placeholder = "Installation Date(MM/dd/yyyy)", required = "required" } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.ActivationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.ActivationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker required", placeholder = "Activation Date(MM/dd/yyyy)", required = "required" } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.DataReceiveInterval, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.DataReceiveInterval, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control required", placeholder = "Data receive Interval", required = "required" } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.HasAMC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.HasAMC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control required", @onchange = "OnChange();" } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group-1" id="HasDate">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.device.AMCExpiredDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-4" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.device.AMCExpiredDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control required", placeholder = "AMCExpireDate(MM/dd/yyyy)", required = "required", title = "Enter AMC Expire Date" } })
                            </div>
                            <button style="margin-left:33%;" id="action" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary col-lg-2 " type="button" name="action" value="SaveDeviceInfo"><strong>Save</strong></button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
}
```

My javascript script is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                debug: true,
                success: "valid"
            });
            $( "#myForm" ).validate({
                rules: {
                    "client.ContactNo": {
                        required: true
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#action").click(function () {               
                if (!$("#myForm").validate()) { // Not Valid
                    return false;
                } else {
                    Save();
                }
            });
   function Save() {

            var frm = $("#myForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Dealer/SaveNewCustomer",
                data: frm,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == "true") {
                        //alert(result);
                        window.location.href = "/Dealer/Customers?Success=true&Message=Customer updated successfully.";
                    }
                    else
                        toastr.error(result);
                }
            });
        }
 </script>
```

Problem is Validation not fire. In If else condition it is showing false and direct store the value in database. Could you please help me? 
Is anything wrong in my code? Give me suggestions please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `.validate()` is only the **initialization** method.
- [`.valid()` is the method used for testing the form](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).

  ```
  if (!$("#myForm").valid()) { ....
  ```

It's a moot point because [your `.ajax()` function belongs inside the `submitHandler` option of the plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler) anyway.  The `submitHandler` callback only fires when the form is valid, thereby you can entirely eliminate your whole if/then `click` handler function (however you must change the `button` element into a `type="submit"`).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });

    $( "#myForm" ).validate({
        rules: {
            "client.ContactNo": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {  // only fires when form is valid
            var frm = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Dealer/SaveNewCustomer",
                data: frm,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == "true") {
                        //alert(result);
                        window.location.href = "/Dealer/Customers?Success=true&Message=Customer updated successfully.";
                    }
                    else
                        toastr.error(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTE**:  If you happen to be using the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin as included within your ASP framework, then the `.validate()` method is constructed and called automatically.  If that's the case, then your call to `.validate()` will be ignored, and you would put any plugin options only within `jQuery.validator.setDefaults()`.

Comment: I used if (!$("#myForm").valid()) and my problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your form tags from your html. Also, you dont have anything with the id of myform. So your trying to validate #myform in your jquery but there is no myform. You would need to add your form tags and give it an id of myform.

Comment: Sparky beat me to it but I dont think  if $("#myForm").validate() would return true so your if statement never runs. You need to use a submithandler as per the documentation here: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/